# c++ amp matrixmultiplication accelerator_view_removed at memory location

Tags: c++-amp

I am playing with the matrixmultiplication project downloadable from the bottom of the site: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/11/02/matrix-multiplication-sample.aspx
When I change the values of M, N, W from 256 to 4096, an unhandled exception is thrown:

Unhandled exception at 0x7630C42D in MatrixMultiplication.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Concurrency::accelerator_view_removed at memory location 0x001CE2F0.

The console output is:

Using device: NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M 
MatrixDiemnsion C(4096x4096) = A(4096x4096) * B(4096x4096) 
CPU(single core) exec completed. 
AMP Simple

The next statement to be executed is leaving the function mxm_amp_simple.
I am using VS2013 Ultimate on Windows 7 Professional N.

Why does this occur and how to prevent this from happening?

EDIT: I have found that the greatest value for M,N,W with which AMP Simple does not lead to a breakpoint being hit is 2800 (M=2800, N=2800, W=2800).
AMP Tiled on the other hand sometimes leads to a breakpoint, and in other cases executes correctly for M,N,W equal to 4096. 
The exception is accompanied by a system error message:

"Display driver stopped responding and has recovered. Display driver NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 331.65 stopped responding and has successfully recovered."

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else needs this.

This issue is most likely caused by Timeout Detection and Recovery (TDR). If  kernel runs for more then 2 seconds windows will kill it and throw `Concurrency::accelerator_view_removed` exception. The easiest way to check this is to wrap code in try / catch bock. E.g.

```
try {
    av_c.synchronize();
} catch (const Concurrency::accelerator_view_removed& e) {
    printf("%s\n", e.what());
}
```

Microsoft has a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nativeconcurrency/2012/03/06/handling-tdrs-in-c-amp/) with more information, including pointers to instructions how to disable it.